# Removing duplicate labels within a given radius

Tags: python, buffer, gis, geospatial, arcgis

I have 500.000 data of house number (address) with longitude and latitude in a particular area, but I don't want there is the same house number within a 50m radius. Do you know how to detect the existence of the same adjacent numbers within a 50m radius?

is there any method in python, PostGIS, ArcGIS, QGIS, or another spatial tool to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: So if you have a up/down+left/right crossing and to the left and up two new streets start, both with numbers 1,2,3 etc. .... you want to discard first 50m of housenumbers of both streets? Just curious. Heads up: asking for 3rd party libs on SO is offtopic and your question might get closed soon ...

Comment: not completely discard or delete, but I just want to detect it so that it can be analyzed in the field related to duplicate data or inappropriate road data

Comment: @Hermawan Wiwid You can calculate it programmatically. For each object calculate the distance to other objects. If the distance is less than 50 m, then check.

Comment: @alexrnov Hello, thanks for the suggestion but that solution works only in a small amount of data (let say less than 50.000) if I have 500.000 data so that would take a very long time to finish.

Comment: @ Hermawan Wiwid Okay, you're right. In this case, you can first determine the sets of objects with the same addresses, and then calculate the distance between the objects in each set. Or use PointDensity() (Spatial Analyst module) with a radius of 50 m for each set. And at the end, combine the results.